# Image fade-in when webpage finishes loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, fadein

I'm trying to have the elements (all in div and img tags) fade in when the webpage loads.

Right now I have the images set to change to a different image onmouseover so I don't want the code for the fade in to interfere with this at all.

If you can help with the code for the fade-in it would be great if you could help identify what parts of the code I can change to change the speed of the fade-in or anything like that.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

If you use jQuery it would be something like this:

```
$("myElement").show("fade", 400);
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery do something simple like :

```
$(function(){
  $('.myFaders').animate({opacity:1},300);
});
```

In your CSS doe something like this:

```
.myFaders{
   opacity: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zGXKT/

Comment: I put those into my document and when I tested the site the images didn't show at all. So I changed the opacity in the CSS document and they appeared but they are still not fading in. Do I tweak the .fadeIn at all?

Comment: updated my answer, and added a fiddle.